# How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, java, oracle

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, x64 architecture, and I specifically need to install [Oracle Java](https://www.java.com/en/). Now I know there are some [instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#install) on the website which I follow but the same website does not [recognize it](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp). Can any one please help me with some instructions? Thanks!

Comment: You want to install JRE (just to run java apps) or JDK (you want to develop java apps)? Also which version you want to install (Java 6, 7 or 8)?

Comment: I want the development kit, the latest, version 8.

Comment: You can simplify installing oracle `jdk/jre` with [this script](https://github.com/neurobin/oraji)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 421, accepted):

#### Using a PPA (Obsolete)

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

You can use [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) (this will download the required files from Oracle and install JDK 8):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

[Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/33871)

Also ensure your `JAVA_HOME` variable has been set to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

For this you can use the following command (see step 3 of Manual Install to see how to make it permanent):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

#### Manual install

The tar.gz provided by Oracle don't have an actual installation process. You just extract those files to a location you want and add them to your path. So the process is the following:

- Download a `.tar.gz` from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (here I will be using `jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz`);
- Extract it to somewhere;
- Move the extracted folder to `/usr/lib/jvm`. This is not required but it is the place where Java runtime software is installed, and where tools like IDE's may search for it:

  ```
  sudo mv /path/to/jdk1.8.0_20 /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
  ```
- Before addin this jdk as an alternative, you can see that the new alternative is not listed:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --query java

  sudo update-alternatives --query javac
  ```
- Next, add the new jdk alternatives (2000 is the priority and feel free to pick a different number):

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre/bin/java 2000

  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin/javac 2000
  ```
- Now you should see the new jdk listed and you can switch between the alternatives with this command:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java

  sudo update-alternatives --config javac
  ```
- Create a file `/etc/profile.d/oraclejdk.sh` with the following content (adapt the paths to reflect the path where you stored your JDK):

  ```
  export J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
  export J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre/bin
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8
  export DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/db
  ```

Done! Those paths will only be recognized after you logout or restart, so if you want to use them right away run `source /etc/profile.d/oraclejdk.sh`.

Comment: Thanks again and I accept the answer but please, can you show me the manual version, I mean how to install the tar.gz file.

Comment: I'm going to assume you know how to follow the instructions to install the tar.gz file.  The problem is that website doesn't have java 8.  So how did you download it?  Did you go to oracle.com?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh The files you want are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: @user244986 See my edit. Please note that the PPA process is more or less the same as the manual one (ie the installation of that package only downloads a script to do basically the same).

Comment: Sorry I didn't even see yes, you are rigth it was JDK 7 all this time, just one question, how did you know which wariable to export, and why?

Comment: @user244986 The only needed exports are the PATH one and maybe JAVA_HOME (some programs use it). The others are copied from the package `oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: using ubuntu 14.04.1 installing by ppa by those 3 lines worked thx

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` if you want to install java 7

Comment: Last version for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty is 8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~1 to get JAVA 8u51 (last version) I found the solution at:  [instalando-o-oracle-jdk-8-no-ubuntu-14-04-lts](http://www.maboroshi.eti.br/blog/2015/07/16/instalando-o-oracle-jdk-8-no-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) (pt-br)

Comment: google `jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Comment: It seems that the `oracle-java8-installer` already puts in the file `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` that makes the exported variables permanent.

Comment: is this same works for Debian too ??