# Problems installing Oracle java 1.8

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to install Oracle java 8. 
I downloaded the .rpm file published by Oracle: 
**jdk-8u20-linux-x64.rpm** and then ran the following commands trying to install it:

```
$ sudo alien jdk-8u20-linux-x64.rpm  --scripts
$ sudo dpkg -i jdk1.8.0-20_1.8.020-1_amd64.deb
```

Those two commands seem to be working ok, and then I try to point java to default to this one, using the following command that fails:
    $ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
I get the message below:

```
update-java-alternatives: directory does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I tried to see what versions are available:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Regards
C

Comment: I found a solution packaged on this website: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

1.Download java

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

2.Open terminal type commant

```
cd Downloads

tar xzvf jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz

sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm

sudo mv ~/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_25/ /usr/lib/jvm/

sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" 0

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javac" 0

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javac

sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

. ~/.bashrc

java -version

echo $JAVA_HOME

echo $PATH
```

Comment: There is a PPA for that.

Comment: I've never set the $JAVA_HOME, and that still seemed to work.