# Javafx is not on the default classpath even with Oracle JDK 1.8

Tags: java, jdk, javafx

I recently installed Oracle JDK 1.8 on my Kubuntu Linux machine following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide. I did the manual install because I couldn't get the easy one to work.

If I've understood correctly, javafx should be included on the default classpath after installing Oracle JDK 1.8. This is not the case for me: I need to manually add the `jfxrt.jar` file to the classpath for each new project.

`Java -version` in terminal gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

How can I fix this so that `jfxrt.jar`is always on the default classpath?

Comment: You have to add `CLASSPATH`. Check my answer for details.

Comment: Please provide the output of `javac -version`.

Comment: Please should the error you had using the PPA, since it's really the most convenient way to install and update Oracle Java on Kubuntu and it helps with environment variables, too.

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662452/why-isnt-javafx-on-the-default-classpath-even-when-i-have-installed-oracle-jdk?noredirect=1#comment47481062_29662452

Comment: @Puce This question was posted at Stack Overflow first and then Sifu was told at Stack Overflow to post it here. This question must belong somewhere. It's being answered here not at SO, so why not keep it here?

Comment: @karel I'm not saying it doesn't belong here. But if you do a cross-posts you should mention that so people are aware of answers given at other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up `CLASSPATH` in `/etc/environment`. Execute the following command in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Add the following lines (all four lines at the end of `/etc/environment`)

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8"
export JAVA_HOME
CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/lib"
export CLASSPATH
```

Alternatively you can add CLASSPATH to `/etc/profile.d/oraclejdk.sh` if you have used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide.

```
export CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/lib"
```

Comment: It shoudln't be needed to add jfxrt.jar to the classpath since it uses the extension mechanism.

Comment: Since I followed the guide specified I tried the alternative method and it works great. Thanks.