# How do I upgrade Java from 8 to 9+ on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't make new projects on NetBeans 8.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 since it has Java 8 not 9.

```
Log Session: Friday, February 15, 2019 at 10:24:48 PM Eastern European Standard Time
System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)
  Operating System        = Linux version 4.15.0-45-generic running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 10.0.2; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = OpenJDK Runtime Environment 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/abdelrahman
  Current Directory       = /home/abdelrahman
  User Directory          = /home/abdelrahman/.netbeans/8.2
  Cache Directory         = /home/abdelrahman/.cache/netbeans/8.2
  Installation            = /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/ergonomics
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/ide
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/extide
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/java
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/apisupport
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/webcommon
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/websvccommon
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/enterprise
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/mobility
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/profiler
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/php
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/harness
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/cnd
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/cndext
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/dlight
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/groovy
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/javafx
                            /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = 
  Application Classpath   = /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/boot.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/core.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/asm-all-5.0.1.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/core-base.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core-base_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core-base_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core-base_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core-base_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ru.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ja.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_pt_BR.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/core_nb_zh_CN.jar:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/home/abdelrahman/netbeans-8.2/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.33.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.util [9.7.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.util.ui [9.6.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.modules [7.48.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.27.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.filesystems [9.10.2 201705191307]
    org.openide.awt [7.67.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.api.progress/1 [1.47.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.api.progress.nb [1.47.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.dialogs [7.42.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.nodes [7.45.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.windows [6.75.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup/1 [1.40.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.text [6.67.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol [1.56.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.swing.outline [1.34.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.explorer [6.62.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.actions [6.39.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.queries/1 [1.43.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.api.templates [1.7.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.filesystems.nb [9.9.2 201612141242]
    org.openide.loaders [7.66.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.api.intent [1.2.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.api.io [1.3.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.io [1.49.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.filesystems.compat8 [9.9.1 201609300101]
    org.openide.execution [9.3.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.upgrader [4.35.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.swing.plaf [1.41.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.projectapi/1 [1.66.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.swing.dirchooser [1.29.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.spi.viewmodel/2 [1.51.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.spi.tasklist/1 [1.35.1.1 1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.spi.quicksearch [1.27.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.spi.palette/1 [1.46.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.spi.navigator/1 [1.37.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings/1 [1.56.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.util/1 [1.64.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.document [1.9.1.3 3 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.lexer/2 [1.63.1.1 1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2/1 [2.16.3.56.3 56 201705191307]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.lib [1.51.1.1 1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.fold/1 [1.45.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent/2 [1.43.1 201609300101]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.guards/1 [1.33.1 201609300101]
```

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: @dessert Although I edited the title but forgot to edit body. Hope it's clear now :)

Comment: @Kulfy There’s still no question – is it “How do I install Java 9?”, or “Which version of NetBeans is available on Ubuntu 18.04?”, or …

Comment: IMO "How do I install Java 9 and use NetBeans 8.2?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX missing, Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091157/javafx-missing-ubuntu-18-04) Read the accepted answer for instructions that are specific to 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

According to [release notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#req_sw) of Netbeans 8.2:

> The tested JDK for this release is JDK 8u101 for Windows, Linux, and OS X. The 8.2 version of the IDE cannot be installed or run on the JDK older than JDK 8.

Moreover, Java 9 and 10 were non-LTS versions of Java which reached their respective end of life in March'18 and September'18. That's why they aren't available in Ubuntu's official repository.

So, if you still want to use NetBeans 8.2, it's better to use it with Java 8. Or if you still want to use Java 8+, use NetBeans 9.0 or 10.0.

Further reading:

- [Java version history - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)
- [How do I install Netbeans 9.0/10.0?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1076408/816190)