# You are using OpenJDK, please Install OpenJFX error?

Tags: java, openjdk, javafx

Hello I am trying to open STM32CubeProgrammer on my Ubuntu system. Once I have installed the program, tried to open it and came up with this error:

[image: Screenshot]

> You are using OpenJDK, Please install OpenJFX
>
> Debian: sudo apt-get install openjfx
>
> or install Oracle JRE

I ran the `sudo apt-get install openjfx` but still the same problem.

Can somebody help me here? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, might you have to set the `JAVAFX_HOME` environment variable maybe? https://askubuntu.com/a/1078414/367990 Or try to reboot or log out and back in, if the variable was already added during the installation, but not applied to your session yet.

Comment: Thanks you for answer, I rebooted but same problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes in STM32CubeProgrammer release v2.2.0](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/release_note/group0/0e/66/57/b4/f9/ee/4f/73/DM00441049/files/DM00441049.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00441049.pdf), under "known problems and limitations", it says

> STM32CubeProgrammer does not work under Ubuntu® 18.04.