# Unable to copy downloaded java from oracle web site to local?

Tags: permissions, java, jdk, oracle

I have downloaded java 1.8.0 to copy from downloads to /usr/local.
And it does not get copied. What is the reason?

as I m following [this](http://opendesignarch.blogspot.in/2015/07/install-sun-jdk-on-ubuntu.html).

And i am stuck at when it said "next, i copied this to local folder where i created the following script."

Comment: "What is the reason?" Tell us the error you get. Otherwise it will be pointless to start answering. Did you use "sudo" when copying?

Comment: I have not used terminal to do this ; i just ctrl+c the extracted jdk folder and Ctrl + v at local folder in filesystem. neither t gives the error nor copies

Comment: @Aevi take a look on my answer

Comment: Yes it helps ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to permissions:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Sep  4  2014 /usr/local/
```

As you can see the directory `/usr/local/` is owned by user `root` and group `root` so you are not able to just copy any file to this directory as a normal user.

To overcome permissions you should use `sudo`:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/java* /usr/local
```

If you want to copy/paste in GUI mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> then use this trick.

From your terminal run `nautilus` as root:

```
sudo nautilus
```

This will open your file manager `nautilus` to use as root, then you can just copy /paste as you want.

**But** be careful a simple error here will be a disaster

Comment: yes it works please can you visit above site and helps me where to create the script which is asked at this site:

Comment: @Aevi the tutorial there is step by step, just tell me what problem are facing?

Comment: i didn't understand "what about upvoting"

Comment: I have upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @Aevi so what is your problem in that link?

Comment: Actullay i am new to ubuntu that is why i m facing problems

Comment: @Aevi as i see the tutorial is just step by step, just move in with it and tell me if you face a problem

Comment: i have done copying the tar file downloaed from oracle site following steps you have posted

Comment: you want to install oracle jave on ubuntu?

Comment: take alook http://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04 this is better to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26180/discussion-between-aevi-and-maythux).