# Cisco Webex meetings not working on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, java, 64-bit, webex

I am trying to join Webex meetings but I am only able to see the list of members present in the meeting. Everytime I try to do so it says "The Audio Device is Unaccessible Now". Also apart from this I am not even able to see presentation. I am just able to see the members who are present in the meeting.

I have installed Java following this [How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I am using Firefox 64 bit.

Please help!