# How can I install OpenJDK on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, java, 16.04, jdk, openjdk

Since I upgraded to the latest version of Ubuntu, I cannot install the Java OpenJDK package needed to compile Android custom ROMs. When I run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, the following error appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  openjdk-7-jdk :
 Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4) E: Unable to correct
 problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I just installed openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-8-jre on 16.04, maybe try them?

Comment: If you fail to install Openjdk, install Oracle jdk by following good instructions here http://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: i guess not all packages are downloaded while installing system..because i haven't these errors on 14.04..

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 58, accepted):

had the same problem too.. but i solved it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: that's Work  Great :D

Answer (score 24):

The one I did on 16.04 was:

### For OpenJDK 8.X

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

### For OpenJDK 9.X

```
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jre
```

**Note**: There was no `openjdk-6-jre` nor `openjdk-7-jre` for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Also there is NO need to install Oracle JDK (Actually OpenJDK is much better than Oracle one for me).

Answer (score 2):

Some feedback with 16.04... If you are installing as part of a "software script" package, you always have to check which version of Java the programs support first.

For example, using `openjdk-8-jre` (newer version) on the install script.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```