# I need Help Installing JDK

Tags: software-installation

Hi I need help installing JDK so I can use Netbeans. When I try and install Netbeans with POL it says missing JDK. Please Help

Comment: [How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04/521154#521154)

Comment: Why are you running the Windows version? You'll get much better results with the native Linux version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and install the Java SDK which comes bundled with NetBeans as a package [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html) so that you can install both at once.

Take note that there is also a Linux version here.  So you can install JDK with NetBeans directly onto Linux without having to install it through PlayOnLinux.  I would suggest trying out the Linux version before trying to install it on POL.

[Click here for instruction on installing JDK+NetBeans on Linux.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html#linux)

Comment: Answer more of my questions please I'm completely new to this

Comment: Just visit the 2 links I posted, specifically the [instructions link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html#linux).  I could give you step-by-step but I would just be rewriting the instructions I posted the link to...

Comment: hey works perfectly thanks. Answer another Q please

Comment: answer more questions of mine please?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require a specific verison, it's a one-command thing:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest JDK from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/

You can also use [this script](https://gist.github.com/P7h/9741922) to download it automatically.

Then install it by extracting the package which you can do by double clicking on the file and selecting extract from the menu. You may also want to add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_91
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Oracle Java is better considering performance and compatibility compared to other implementations of JDK.

Comment: -1 You can't just say "install it." You need to provide instructions for doing so. And I know from experience that installing Oracle's JDK is not the easiest task.

Comment: @AndroidDev I don't think so, but I will add the instructions, which is extracting the package, and in some cases setting JAVA_HOME and PATH.