# Problem after installing Arduino IDE 1.8.0

Tags: 14.04, ide, arduino

I am using ubuntu 14.04 I tried to install Arduino IDE the last version 1.8.0 because when I installed it by terminal it was 2009 1.0.5 version

1. I download the last version
2. Extract the file arduino-1.8.0-linux64.tar.xz
3. Moved the result folder to /opt/ directory for global use`sudo mv arduino-1.8.0 /opt`
4. `cd /opt/arduino-1.8.0/`
5. `chmod +x install.sh`
6. `./install.sh`

It created a desktop icon but when i try to start it.

it is just show this screen for seconds and do nothing :
[image]

**Update:**

I tried to run it from terminal `./arduino` it show that
[image]

Comment: Already in the repositories. Install using `sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core`.

Comment: I did that but it installed very old version  2009 1.0.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for the error I found in terminal and find it may caused by old java version

and I upgrade java version by [the way in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/521154/429234)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: yes it need java version upgrade