# java crashed with SIGABRT in WTFCrash()

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, jre

on a newly installed Ubuntu 16.04, I was receiving `Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error`. there is a [bug issue reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1725841) about OpenJDK with this error, therefore  I  [completely removed Java](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/696880) and [manually installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/521154/696880) Oracle packages in JVM folder. yet I receive the same error.

[image]

Comment: I'd advise you not to call a method called "WTFCrash"...

Comment: But on a serious note, I'm facing the same issue on openjdk-9, so upgrading to that is not a good option I guess.

Comment: I see the same problem on an official Ubuntu Dell-laptop with 16.04.  My desktop HP machine (which I have installed Ubuntu on my self) has never shown this symptom over almost 5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure it out.there were two reasons, one was because of the Nvidia driver which I changed the driver and the other problem was occurring from Eclipse.
I do not know what is GTK version 3 or 2 in eclipse, or for instance, Eclipse Neon was using version 2 and Oxygen version 3, but [in eclipse forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1071268/), I found that people after upgrading to GTK3 faced the problem.
so in eclipse.ini file I added `--launcher.GTK_version 2` before `--launcher.appendVmargs -vm` and till now I did not face the problem anymore.