# Ubuntu 18.04LTS - How to solve an "Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04, has experienced an internal error"

Tags: 18.04, crash

Randomly after a power on of the computer, I have this error "Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04, has experienced an internal error".

Do you know what can be the root cause?
Do you know how to solve this issue?
Do you know some tools in order to investigate this issue?
Cf. Screenshot: 
[Internal Report 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB8EI.png) ; 
[Internal report 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PDkt.png)

Comment: Googling the error about java crashing gives this https://askubuntu.com/questions/972951/java-crashed-with-sigabrt-in-wtfcrash

Comment: Simply click "Ignore future problems of this type". You can't do anything about this problem anyway, since it is about an unofficial package and the crash won't be reported to the developers.