# How to install Java9 with JavaFX?

Tags: 16.04, java, javafx

I installed Java9 as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/521154/580653). This works without any problems for any projects I tried without JavaFX. Unfortunately my company runs its UIs with JavaFX and those packages seem to be missing.

I also evaluated using the openjdk plus the [openjfx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244308/1374536) package, but this does not exist for Java9 yet.

What would be the way to install Java9 with JavaFX?

Comment: According to the Oracle website, JavaFX is included with standard JDK and JRE bundles since 7u6. So if you have installed JDK 9 you should also have JavaFX. Are you sure you are using the JDK 9 you have installed?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Running `java -version` gives java 9.0.4.

Comment: In that case, it may be worth considering updating your question to include information about what you are trying. For example, is the problem occurring during compiling or when trying to launch an application? Are any errors given and if so, what are they? Etc.

Comment: Please post the complete output of `java -version` since it's crucial to see which version of JDK you have installed (you posted a link to instructions for OpenJDK 8 and the `java` version is 9.x).

Answer (score 0):

To install Java 9 with JavaFX, you should download the JDK 9 from Oracle, which includes JavaFX by default. If you have installed JDK 9 but cannot access JavaFX, ensure your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to the JDK 9 directory and that your path variable includes JAVA_HOME. If JavaFX is still missing, you might have a JRE instead of a JDK, or your installation did not complete correctly. In such cases, reinstalling the JDK 9 should resolve the issue.