# Oracle-jdk8-installer was not found While java is installed

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

I installed java by downloading its source. I set java path, it's OK and works but when I want to install another app (e.g Apache-Ambari-server with `ambari-server start`) I get this error:

```
E: Release 'ambari-server*.deb' for 'oracle-jdk8-installer' was not found
```

Why do I get an error when I have java on my system?

Edited:

Install JAVA:
Add path to `/etc/profile`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java

source /etc/profile
```

Comment: What java do you have? How did you install it?

Comment: @Yoran Jansen. I edited the question, please read again.

Comment: Please take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04#521154 for more information