# What to do with java tar.gz after installation?

Tags: java, jdk

I am new to linux so want to know whether the java tar.gz file can be deleted or not from the local system once java installation is completed ?

Comment: I believe the answer of this question is quite similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa . Look at the manual section.

Comment: If you have followed instructions such as these: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml you will see that point 4 of the Install section says: 'Delete the .tar.gz file if you want to save disk space.'

Comment: Actually, Installation of Java is done, but I want to know that if after installation, the downloaded tar.gz file can be deleted or not permanently from the download folder... hope I imply my questions clearly. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed 'Delete the .tar.gz file if you want to save disk space.' line while installation. But I appreciate your time and answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the standard instructions for installing the Oracle Java:

- [Linux 64-bit installation instructions for Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml)

specify in Point 4 of the Install section:

> Delete the .tar.gz file if you want to save disk space.

Another option, if disk space is not such an issue, is to archive the installation file in case reinstallation is required at a future stage...